# How can i change server administrator name and password

Tags: windows, powershell, local, administrator

I need to change the local administrator name and password on servers to those that are contained in a .csv

The CSV file contains a list with all the information in it whereby the Server, Administrator name and Passwords are different on each line

The csv is headed by three columns  - Server,Admin,PW

How could this be done using Powershell?

I know i can set them all the same using this but they need to be as per each csv line.

```
foreach ($strComputer in get-content  c:\Servers.txt)
{

$Admin=[adsi]("WinNT://" + $strComputer + "/Administrator, user")
$Admin.psbase.rename("Newname")
$Admin.SetPassword("NewPW")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ( not tested ):

```
import-csv c:\servers.txt | % {

$Admin=[adsi]("WinNT://" + $($_.Server) + "/Administrator, user")
$Admin.psbase.rename($($_.Admin))
$Admin.SetPassword($($_.PW))
$Admin.SetInfo() # I think it's needed
}
```

Comment: Thanks i'll test at let you know :)

Comment: Glad to help. Remeber to accept it as the answer if solve your question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Import-Csv instead of get-content. then you can adress the variables by using the header names.
asuming you have a file like:

```
Server,Admin,PW
bla1,bla2,bla3
blaA,blaB,blaC
```

the output of

```
foreach ($line in Import-Csv c:\Servers.txt) { echo $line.server }
```

would be:

```
bla1
blaA
```

just to complete your code, try this example:

```
foreach ($line in Import-Csv c:\Servers.txt)
{
$Admin=[adsi]("WinNT://" + $line.Server + "/Administrator, user")
$Admin.psbase.rename($line.Admin)
$Admin.SetPassword($line.PW)
}
```

Comment: Thanks again yes that worked...will do testing but great help form you all!